# Specify custom gitattributes file location for git archive

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-archive

I'd like to expose `git archive`, but have a way for users to ask for some files or globs to be excluded, so the resulting archive file is not very big.

Normally you'd write the file/glob list to `.gitattributes` and then run `git archive`. But this means only one person can ask for an archive per on-disk repository, since they have to write their ignore-export list to `.gitattributes`, then get the archive, before yielding to someone else. Also this means that whatever settings you had in there previously get clobbered.

Is there a way I could write to /tmp/attributes-1 or another similar temp file, and tell `git archive` to read that .gitattributes file instead of `$repo/.gitattributes`? Reading the doc string, it doesn't seem like it.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Answer (score 2):

Did you miss the [`--worktree-attributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#git-archive---worktree-attributes) option of `git archive`?

> **`--worktree-attributes`**
>
> Look for attributes in `.gitattributes` files in the working tree as
>   well (see the section called “ATTRIBUTES”).
>
> ...
>
> Note that attributes are by default taken from the `.gitattributes`
>   files in the tree that is being archived. **If you want to tweak the
>   way the output is generated after the fact (e.g. you committed without
>   adding an appropriate `export-ignore` in its `.gitattributes`), adjust
>   the checked out `.gitattributes` file as necessary and use
>   `--worktree-attributes` option**. Alternatively you can keep necessary
>   attributes that should apply while archiving any tree in your
>   `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file.

So you must checkout a temporary work-tree, set the desired gitattributes there and use the `--worktree-attributes` option.

Comment: Checking out a temporary working tree also modifies the repository right? So I can't perform more than one operation at a time.

Comment: This is how you can checkout a temporary work-tree without modifying the repository: `tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"; mkdir "$tmpdir"/worktree; cd "$tmpdir"/worktree; GIT_INDEX_FILE="$tmpdir"/index git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git checkout HEAD .`

Comment: @KevinBurke I posted a separate question with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322079/how-to-safely-checkout-a-temporary-working-tree-from-a-git-repository