# How to safely checkout a temporary working tree from a git repository?

Tags: git

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42312472/6394138) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311670/specify-custom-gitattributes-file-location-for-git-archive) I proposed a solution that required checking out a temporary working tree, but it had to be performed safely, without clobbering the source repository in any way. In particular, the operation must be safe to run concurrently with other git operations. I believed that it could be done, and didn't elaborate it in the answer, and then had to provide a comment showing how to do that. This self-answered question fills the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script checks out a working tree into the current directory without affecting the source repository in any way (in particular it can be executed on a repository to which there is no write access, e.g. a repository belonging to another user).

Usage:

```
git-checkout-tmp-worktree repo_path [revision]
```

Examples:

```
git-checkout-tmp-worktree ~/myrepo1
git-checkout-tmp-worktree ~/myrepo1 HEAD^^
```

**git-checkout-tmp-worktree**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 || $# -gt 2 ]]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $(basename "$0") repo_path [revision]"
    exit 1
fi

repo="${1}"
revision="${2:-HEAD}"

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'" EXIT
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$tmpdir/index" git --git-dir="$repo"/.git checkout "$revision" .
```